# Как убрать такое выделение в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

подскажите как можно убрать такое выделение. Т.е нажимаю на див и он выделяет все дивы. Очень неудобно ибо не могу понять где заканчивается данный див
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрать выделение можно так:

```
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false -- Подсветка синтаксиса (поместите курсор внутри переменной)
```

так же вариант:

```
"editor.selectionHighlight": false -- Подсветка выделения (похожие фрагменты в документе)
```

наверное то что вам нужно:

```
"editor.matchBrackets": false -- Подсветка соответствующих скобок
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640244/9363441) статья где можно найти дополнительную информацию.